# I wish to calculate Regression for my data, but I am getting this error regarding data frame?

Tags: r, linear-regression, magrittr

```
Regression <- top50 %>%
                lm(Length.~Popularity) %>%
                summary(Regression)
```

Error I am getting:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : cannot coerce class ‘"formula"’ to a data.frame

Comment: You need to tell `lm` where the data is, e.g., `lm(Length ~ Popularity, data = .)`.

Comment: Why not `summary(lm(...))` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use pipes, try :

```
library(magrittr)
top50 %>% lm(Length.~Popularity, data = .) %>% summary
```

which is similar to

```
summary(lm(Length.~Popularity, data = top50))
```

Using reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
mtcars %>% lm(mpg~cyl, data = .) %>% summary

#Call:
#lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = .)

#Residuals:
#   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
#-4.981 -2.119  0.222  1.072  7.519 

#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)   37.885      2.074   18.27  < 2e-16 ***
#cyl           -2.876      0.322   -8.92  6.1e-10 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#Residual standard error: 3.21 on 30 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.726,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.717 
#F-statistic: 79.6 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 6.11e-10
```